# Laravel website not indexed

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, google-search

Week ago I uploaded my Laravel website to a web server, but couldn't find it on Google. Every other site I uploaded was indexed and available in a few days time. I don't know what is the problem. I tried searching by keywords and site:example.com and site:www.example.com, nothing found. Google Webmaster Tools also says no data to show. What could be the problem?

Comment: it is not off-topic! It couldn't be coincidence that none of (many!) plain PHP websites never needed to be manually added for indexed and that both of Laravel websites do! It had to do something with Laravel! And Laravel is PHP framework used for programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you block search engines using `<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />`? Otherwise Google still needs some time to index your website.
If your are not sure, that Google recognized your site, you can add it [here](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url). However, there is no warranty that Google will index your site in the next time.

Comment: I am not using robots.txt. I tried adding it your way, but I don't why I never had issues like this before with non-Laravel website. Am I missing some of the Laravel configuration?

Comment: I don't know lavarel, but if you can access your site in any Browser, Google can access it too. If you have not blocked search engines, Google still needs some time to index your site. Unfortunatly, Google does not provide information, when and how the websites are indexed.

Comment: Google can find it now after manually adding it for indexing! Thanks!